# Facebook audio Upload of mp4 format

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, mp4, tumblr

Need help/idea on this.

I have to create a `mp4` audio file and then have to upload it on `facebook`, `twitter` and `tumblr`.

I know there is no specific API for this there. But is there any other way out?

I also know i can upload files on separate server and then can provide the link. But i want it to play there only as video's in facebook.

Any ideas on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can utilize open graph, i.e. create a web page with og:audio related meta tags, see the following doc (scroll towards the bottom):
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

then anytime a user/page/app likes a page, it is uploaded to their facebook

hope this helps

Comment: in the doc linked above there is example of mp4 format which is the official standard for mpeg4 which should work in safari (see og:video example)

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it from opengraph see if this link is suitable for you https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it by open graph protocol of facebook